# Make DIVs in Accordion/Collapsible stay fixed at top and bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok i'll try very hard to explain exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

I know that if I want a div to stay at the bottom of a page I can simply do this..

```
<div id="foo" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0: width: 100%">
   blah text
</div>
```

But I don't want this to always be at the bottom of the page..

I have code like this..

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
                function toggle_visibility(id) {
                   var e = document.getElementById(id);
                   if(e.style.display == 'block')
                      e.style.display = 'none';"
                   else
                      e.style.display = 'block';
                }
            </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="firstDiv" style="display: block;">
   ......
</div>
<div id="secondDiv" style="display: none;">
   ......
</div>
<div id="thirdDiv" style="display: none;">
   ......
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

..repeated 20 times or w/e..

```
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do something like http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/collapsible.html

BUT i really don't want to use someone elses library if at all possible... I'm open to using jQuery etc, just don't want to use someone elses library if all possible unless its very bare bones and not a FULL library.

I only know how to hide and show the current ones HTML.  I know i would prolly have to do something like..

```
if (e.id = "firstDiv") {
   secondDiv.style.display = 'none';
   thirdDiv.style.display = 'none';
} elseif { ....
  ....
}
```

Ok so what I want to be able to do is if i have a TON of data inside the [firstDiv] and its so much data that the page has a scroll bar and the [secondDiv] and [thirdDiv] would normally pushed all the way down the page...  I want [secondDiv] and [thirdDiv] to stack ontop of eachother and always at the bottom of the page...

But then if I click on [secondDiv] then the [firstDiv] contents will obviously disappear, but I want [firstDiv] to stay at top of page no matter what, then [secondDiv] to be right under neath it which will then show its HTML while [thirdDiv] will still stay static at the bottom of the page....

Then if I was to click on [thirdDiv] then it would just then be [firstDiv] [secondDiv] and [thirdDiv] stacked in order at the very top while now of course showing the HTML of the [thirdDiv]...

LOOOONG explaination later i'm wanting to do a Collapseable system that hides the other divs content while keeping them in order HOWEVER the twist is that the divs below the [firstDiv] always still show up at the bottom of the page no matter what.

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/78fgmov9/

Comment: Its not working for me friend, when i open 2 and 3 then the rest get pushed with a weird blue background and then just stay there

Comment: any title thats lower than the bottom stays there until its pulled up, thats what its supposed to do, what should they be doing instead?

Comment: when i go and scroll down the page, they should stay at the bottom of the page not stay static where it was last at.  for example with your example if i expand 9... then i expand 1 2 3 and 4.. the rest stack at the bottom... but when i go and scroll down the page, they just stay there they don't stay stuck at the bottom as i'm scrolling.  Also only the one I click would need to expand, the rest would 'hide' their Content like a normal accordion/collapsible div effect

Comment: what you are asking for is non trivial. the fiddle i made is a start. if you want help on SO for this you would need to come up with some code that accomplishes at least some of what you would like it to do, beyond that, you need to hire a developer.

Comment: SO is *not* a place where you say "I want a webpage that does X" and we provide code for it

Comment: ... what you did is broken. it doesn't even come close to the code i had already created though.  not sure why your getting upset.  I already had a working accordion code working, i needed to know how to get it to stay fixed..  even though i had to update and answer my own question using a terribly arcaic way i still found my answer.. but we have to agree that what you had did isn't anywhere close.. sorry friend i do appreciate your attempt though

Comment: not getting upset :-) I just don't see how your code attempt shows the menu items getting fixed at the bottom, so if I misread where your original code does that, please correct me

Comment: also if you want your code rewritten you should look at the code review stack exchange

Comment: the very first example friend shows the code being fixed at the bottom :) i went ahead and added the finished example for you to see what I was looking for

Comment: @chiliNUT This is definitely not Code Review material. Please read [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving and having to do this myself.  My answer is TERRIBLY UGLY, but it does work...  I would love if anyone could help re-write it so its not so ugly I would greatly appreciate it...

I ended up having to create a Header to act as the (Accordion Header) then a div below it that acted as the div that held the results of the HTML/Content..

Then each Accordion Header I just set onclick="toggle_visibility('firstDivHeader');" or whatever the header that was clicked and then it did the following..

http://jsfiddle.net/t8Le7qqv/  - I wanted to add finished result incase anyone wanted to know how to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function toggle_visibility(id) {
            if (id == 'firstDivHeader')
            {

            document.getElementById('firstDivResults').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.top = '0';
            document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('secondDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.top = '';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.bottom = '82px';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('thirdDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.top = '';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.bottom = '41px';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('forthDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.top = '';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.bottom = '0px';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';



            } else if (id == 'secondDivHeader')
            {

            document.getElementById('firstDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.top = '0';
            document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('secondDivResults').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.top = '41px';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('thirdDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.top = '';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.bottom = '41px';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('forthDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.top = '';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.bottom = '0px';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';



            } else if (id == 'thirdDivHeader')
            {


            document.getElementById('firstDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.bottom = '0';
            document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('secondDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.top = '41px';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('thirdDivResults').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.top = '82px';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.bottom = '0';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('forthDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.top = '';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.bottom = '0px';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';



            } else if (id == 'forthDivHeader')
            {

            document.getElementById('firstDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.top = '0';
            document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
            document.getElementById('firstDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('secondDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.top = '41px';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
            document.getElementById('secondDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('thirdDivResults').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.top = '82px';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
            document.getElementById('thirdDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';

            document.getElementById('forthDivResults').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.top = '123px';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.bottom = '';
            document.getElementById('forthDivHeader').style.position = 'fixed';



            }
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the design pattern. It really helped me when I was looking to build something similar to what you had done. Here's my version as per your re-write request :) Things to note: I'm using jQuery selectors rather the the javascript ones you used, my divs are named differently and my row height is different, but you'll get the idea.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {

    // Setup the accordion divs
    var sectionHeaderIds = ["#sectionOneHeader", "#sectionTwoHeader", "#sectionThreeHeader",
    "#sectionFourHeader", "#sectionFiveHeader", "#sectionSixHeader"];
    var sectionDetails = ["#sectionOneDetail", "#sectionTwoDetail", "#sectionThreeDetail",
    "#sectionFourDetail", "#sectionFiveDetail", "#sectionSixDetail"];

    var rowHeight = 30;
    var chosenSectionId = 0;
    var numSections = sectionHeaderIds.length;

    // Get the index of the selected section
    for (var i = 0; i < numSections; i++) {
        if (sectionDetails[i] == id) {
            chosenSectionId = i;
        }
    }

    // Loop through the divs
    for (var i = 0; i < numSections; i++) {

        var sectionHeader = $(sectionHeaderIds[i]);
        var sectionDetail = $(sectionDetails[i]);

        sectionHeader.css('position','fixed');

        if (sectionDetails[i] == id) {
            sectionDetail.css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            sectionDetail.css('display', 'none');
        }

        sectionHeader.css('top',(i <= chosenSectionId) ? i * rowHeight : '');
        sectionHeader.css('bottom',(i > chosenSectionId) ? (numSections - i - 1) * rowHeight : '');
    }
}
```